# triangle inequality theorem

Tags: geometry

triangle inequality theorem states Sum of any $2$ sides must be greater than $3$rd side.

I am doing exercises in my text book. For example, I am checking if $10,3,5$ can form a triangle.

$10+3 > 5$
$10+5 > 3$
  $5+3 > 10$ : False 
Third condition is false and hence triangle cannot be formed.

For every problem, all the conditions are tested or we stop when any of the condition fails.

But, can't we just say "Sum of shorter sides must be greater than  the longest side" and always check this condition only?

i.e., we check add $5$ and $3$ (shorter sides) and compare with 10(longer side). if this test pass, other two tests must also pass, right?

In summary, I need to add two shorter sides and compare with the longer side instead of testing all three conditions. Am I correct?

Comment: Because if the longest side is on the left of the $>$ sign, then that side alone is greater than the other side of the inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's true.

Let $ a <= b <= c $, if $ c < a + b $ then:

$$ b <= c < a + b <= a + c $$ 
Therefore 
$$ b < a + c $$

Likewise:
$$ a <= c < a + b <= c + b $$ 
$$ a < c + b $$

To us humans, it's easy enough to immediately find the biggest of $3$ numbers, and easier to write just one comparison than $3$. However, if you think about it, to actually find who's the biggest one you have to do $2$ comparisons already, however trivial they may be. So it's not THAT big of an improvement, at least from a machine's POV and if you can tolerate the extra writing.

Comment: thanks, It was better if the text books could have given this explanation also which was meant to be for students.

Comment: You could write it as $\min(a, b, c)+(a+b+c-\min(a, b, c)-\max(a, b, c)) > \max(a, b, c)$, doing the min and max computations once and saving the results.